# Celery does not not registered my tasks only in AWS

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, terraform, celery, flower

[The structure of the Terraform for dev environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVJ2M.png)We have an application that is deployed with Terraform in AWS.

The Terraform is responsible of creation of all resources needed is AWS, including the celery, beat and flower and the Flask app ec2 instances.

My celery is perfectly running on localhost with all the tasks correctly registered. However, when i deploy the app in AWS, i got a `NotRegistered("<name of the >")` in the flower dashboard. And i also got `Received unregistered task of type: <name of the task>` in the logs of the celery worker in CloudWatch logs.

```
# The file in the terraform where i execute the command that run celery in production
command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 15; celery -A api.celery worker -E --loglevel=debug --without-mingle --without-gossip --without-heartbeat -Ofair"]
```

[The structure of our Terraform infra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVJ2M.png)

**Below the Terraform that is responsible to create our `dev` environment when we push to dev branch.**

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// APPLICATION
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["example-namesace-all-vpc"]
  }
}
data "aws_subnet_ids" "private_subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = {
    "namespace" = "example-namesace"
    "stage"     = "all"
    "tier"      = "Private"
  }
}
data "aws_security_group" "ecs_security_group" {
  name = "example-namesace-all_ecs"
}
data "aws_db_instance" "database" {
  db_instance_identifier = "example-namesace-dev-dev-rds"
}

//
// DEV ENVIRONMENT
//
///////////////////////////////
module "dev_example-namesace_backend" {
  source    = "../modules/ecs_cluster_service"
  namespace = "example-namesace"
  stage     = "dev"

  app_name                = "example-namesace-dev-backend"
  app_fqdn                = "dev.api.example-namesace.com"
  cloudfront_distribution = "E3ONVBGFBH74MH"

  # Container info
  #############################
  app_container_name = "flask_container"
  app_image_name     = var.app_image_api_name
  app_image_tag      = var.app_image_tag
  app_host_port      = 4000
  app_container_port = 4000

  app_container_cpu    = 256
  app_container_memory = 512
  app_reserved_cpu     = 256
  app_reserved_memory  = 512

  app_desired_count     = 1
  app_container_command = ["gunicorn", "--worker-class", "eventlet", "--timeout", "0", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:4000", "manage:app"]
  app_heathcheck_path   = "/"

  # Other settings
  #############################
  app_target_group          = "back-tg"
  alb_priority              = 400
  cloudwatch_log_group_name = "back-logs"
  security_groups           = [data.aws_security_group.ecs_security_group.id]
  subnets                   = data.aws_subnet_ids.private_subnets.ids

  app_env_vars = {
    DATABASE                      = "postgres"
    FLASK_ENV                     = "dev"
    SQL_HOST                      = data.aws_db_instance.database.address
    SQL_PORT                      = data.aws_db_instance.database.port
    FLASK_APP                     = "api/__init__.py"
    APP_FOLDER                    = "/home/app/api"
    LC_ALL                        = "C"
    ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS = "[\"json-file\",\"awslogs\"]",
    CELERY_BROKER_URL             = "redis://${module.redis.endpoint}:6379/0"
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND         = "redis://${module.redis.endpoint}:6379/0"
  }

  app_env_secrets = {
    JWT_SECRET_KEY        = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.JWT_SECRET_KEY.arn
    SECRET_KEY            = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.SECRET_KEY.arn
    SENDGRID_API_KEY      = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.SENDGRID_API_KEY.arn
    POSTGRES_USER         = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.POSTGRES_USER.arn
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD     = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.POSTGRES_PASSWORD.arn
    POSTGRES_DB           = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.POSTGRES_DB.arn
    CLOUDINARY_NAME       = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.CLOUDINARY_NAME.arn
    CLOUDINARY_API_KEY    = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY.arn
    CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET.arn
  }
}

# //
# // CELERY WORKER DEV ENVIRONMENT
# //
# ///////////////////////////////
module "dev_celery_worker" {
  source    = "../modules/ecs_cluster_service"
  namespace = "example-namesace"
  stage     = "dev"

  app_name                = "example-namesace-dev-celery-worker"
  app_fqdn                = "celery-worker.dev.planning.example-namesace.com"
  cloudfront_distribution = "E3ONVBGFBH74MH"

  # Container info
  #############################
  app_container_name = "worker_celery_container"
  app_image_name     = var.app_image_celery_name
  app_image_tag      = "0.0.2"
  app_host_port      = 5000
  app_container_port = 5000

  app_container_cpu    = 256
  app_container_memory = 512
  app_reserved_cpu     = 256
  app_reserved_memory  = 512

  app_desired_count = 1
  # app_container_command   = ["sleep", "3600"]
  app_container_command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /home/app/; C_FAKEFORK=1 celery -A api.celery worker -D -E --loglevel=info -Ofair -P solo"]
  app_heathcheck_path   = "/"
  # Other settings
  #############################
  app_target_group          = "web-celery-tg"
  alb_priority              = 900
  cloudwatch_log_group_name = "celery-worker-logs"
  security_groups           = [data.aws_security_group.ecs_security_group.id]
  subnets                   = data.aws_subnet_ids.private_subnets.ids

  app_env_vars = {
    DATABASE                            = "postgres"
    FLASK_ENV                           = "dev"
    FLASK_DEBUG                         = 1
    SQL_HOST                            = data.aws_db_instance.database.address
    SQL_PORT                            = data.aws_db_instance.database.port
    APP_SETTINGS                        = "api.config.Config"
    FLASK_APP                           = "api/__init__.py"
    APP_FOLDER                          = "/home/app/api"
    LC_ALL                              = "C"
    ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS       = "[\"json-file\",\"awslogs\"]"
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND               = "redis://${module.redis.endpoint}:6379/0"
    CELERY_BROKER_URL                   = "redis://${module.redis.endpoint}:6379/0"
  }
}

//
// CELERY DASHBOARD DEV ENVIRONMENT
//
///////////////////////////////
module "dev_celery_dashboard" {
  source    = "../modules/ecs_cluster_service"
  namespace = "example-namesace"
  stage     = "dev"

  app_name                = "example-namesace-dev-celery-dashboard"
  app_fqdn                = "celery-dashboard.dev.planning.example-namesace.com"
  cloudfront_distribution = "E3ONVBGFBH74MH"

  # Container info
  #############################
  app_container_name = "dashboard_celery_container"
  app_image_name     = var.app_image_celery_name
  app_image_tag      = "0.0.2"
  app_host_port      = 5555
  app_container_port = 5555

  app_container_cpu    = 256
  app_container_memory = 512
  app_reserved_cpu     = 256
  app_reserved_memory  = 512

  app_desired_count     = 1
  app_container_command = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /home/app/; C_FAKEFORK=1 celery -A api.celery --broker=redis://${module.redis.endpoint}:6379/0 flower --port=5555"]
  app_heathcheck_path   = "/"
  # Other settings
  #############################
  app_target_group          = "dashboard-celery-tg"
  alb_priority              = 800
  cloudwatch_log_group_name = "celery-dashboard-logs"
  security_groups           = [data.aws_security_group.ecs_security_group.id]
  subnets                   = data.aws_subnet_ids.private_subnets.ids

  app_env_vars = {
    DATABASE                            = "postgres"
    FLASK_ENV                           = "dev"
    FLASK_DEBUG                         = 1
    SQL_HOST                            = data.aws_db_instance.database.address
    SQL_PORT                            = data.aws_db_instance.database.port
    APP_SETTINGS                        = "api.config.Config"
    FLASK_APP                           = "api/__init__.py"
    APP_FOLDER                          = "/home/app/api"
    LC_ALL                              = "C"
    ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS       = "[\"json-file\",\"awslogs\"]"
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND               = "redis://${module.redis.endpoint}:6379/0"
    CELERY_BROKER_URL                   = "redis://${module.redis.endpoint}:6379/0"
  }
}

//
// CELERY BEAT DEV ENVIRONMENT
//
///////////////////////////////
module "dev_celery_beat" {
  source    = "../modules/ecs_cluster_service"
  namespace = "example-namesace"
  stage     = "dev"

  app_name                = "example-namesace-dev-celery-beat"
  app_fqdn                = "celery-beat.dev.planning.example-namesace.com"
  cloudfront_distribution = "E3ONVBGFBH74MH"

  # Container info
  #############################
  app_container_name = "beat_celery_container"
  app_image_name     = var.app_image_celery_name
  app_image_tag      = "0.0.2"
  app_host_port      = 5000
  app_container_port = 5000

  app_container_cpu    = 256
  app_container_memory = 512
  app_reserved_cpu     = 256
  app_reserved_memory  = 512

  app_desired_count = 1
  # app_container_command   = ["sleep", "3600"]
  app_container_command = ["/bin/sh","-c", "cd /home/app/; python -m pip install celery_sqlalchemy_scheduler==0.3.0; C_FAKEFORK=1 celery -A api.celery beat --scheduler=celery_sqlalchemy_scheduler.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --loglevel=info"]
  app_heathcheck_path   = "/"

  # Other settings
  #############################
  app_target_group          = "web-celery-tg"
  alb_priority              = 1600
  cloudwatch_log_group_name = "celery-beat-logs"
  security_groups           = [data.aws_security_group.ecs_security_group.id]
  subnets                   = data.aws_subnet_ids.private_subnets.ids

  app_env_vars = {
    DATABASE                            = "postgres"
    FLASK_ENV                           = "dev"
    FLASK_DEBUG                         = 1
    SQL_HOST                            = data.aws_db_instance.database.address
    SQL_PORT                            = data.aws_db_instance.database.port
    APP_SETTINGS                        = "api.config.Config"
    FLASK_APP                           = "api/__init__.py"
    APP_FOLDER                          = "/home/app/api"
    LC_ALL                              = "C"
    ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS       = "[\"json-file\",\"awslogs\"]"
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND               = "redis://${module.redis.endpoint}:6379/0"
    CELERY_BROKER_URL                   = "redis://${module.redis.endpoint}:6379/0"
  }
}
```

Below the structure of the application that is concerned
[image]
[image]

I have no problems in local. All my tasks are registered and executed succesfully but i am wondering why not in AWS.

All help would be welcome and appreciated.

PS: I am not running celery with `celeryd`. Way be i would be better but i don't no. If anyone can point me in this direction, it would appreciated also.
The architecture of the app also verify complex. So if you need more details, fell free to asked me  more details in order to help as best as possible.

Comment: When it runs on AWS how does it resolve "redis" hostname? I wonder perhaps `redis://redis:6379/0` is an invalid URL? Also, I recommend using different Redis "databases" for broker and result backend (you use db 0 for both).

Comment: Hi @DejanLekic, the redis is perfectly resolved in AWS. Something like this redis://dev.xj7ngfew6.ng.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/0. I cange the broker and the result but also same errors. I can give you some details of the code if you want.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check your app environment settings i.e. if any logic does not revolve around APP_ENV. The reason for unregistered task(s) is because at Celery could not get the tasks registered before receiving the task execution. You can create a task in your main file for test and check if the task gets registered also, provide a shareable version of the code in a repo for further understanding.