# Deploy Celery worker and celery beat with Terraform in AWS

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, terraform, celery, celerybeat

We have a Flask app in our company in which we implement Celery along with a beat scheduler. Everything works fine in local. But the problems come when i deploy all in production with Terraform and AWS.

I think, we are not using the best practices for celery deployment in production.

Can anybody guide me trough the best process to deply such an app using Terraform. I think the main issue resides here with Terraform.

Thank you for feedbacks. Everything could be valuable.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @MarkoE Look at this question i posted a couple of day before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71653301/celery-does-not-not-registered-my-tasks-only-in-aws?noredirect=1#comment126645781_71653301

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase: what have you already tried in Terraform? :)

Comment: @MarkoE I try to deploy both our Flask application and Celery using Terraform with multi environments setup as i told earlier in my question. The problem i faced is in the post i mention to you. Thanks !

Comment: Without any Terraform code, it's hard to understand what is really going on, so please update the question with what you already have, what errors do you face etc.

Comment: @MarkoE I'm going to update it right now.

Comment: @MarkoE Have you check the upfdates i made in my previous post about Terraform ?